# Stop scrolling upon reaching specific section with the slider

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to reach the effect similar to https://www.apple.com/iphone-13/
I.e. when user scrolls and reaches a section with slider, slider sticks to the top of the page, scrolling stops in favor of switching slides. When all the slides have been shown, scrolling continues.
How can I utilize mousewheel event to stop scrolling and start switching slides instead upon fixing the element?
Thanks!

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.slider');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollFromTop = window.pageYOffset
        if(scrollFromTop <= container.offsetTop) {
            container.classList.add('fixed')
      /*slides.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.remove('active')
      })
      for(let i = 0; slides.length > i; i++) {
      slides[i].classList.add('active');
      }*/
        }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #666;
}
section.slider {
  background-color: #e03c0b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.slide {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #888;
}
.slide.active {
  display: block;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking for is to switch slides by scrolling then you can add a sticky div inside a container and use javascript to translate the slide container on scroll. Note: there will have to be some bugs worked out as I just whipped this up quick but it should give you an idea of the concept and get you started.

Something like the following:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.slide-container')
const slides = document.querySelector('.slides')

const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect()
const slideRect = slides.getBoundingClientRect()

const containerTop = containerRect.top
const containerHeight = containerRect.height
const slideWidth = slideRect.width

const scrollDistance = containerHeight - window.innerHeight
const slideDistance = slideWidth - window.innerWidth

const getProgress = (start, distance, scroll) => {
  return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, (scroll - start) / distance))
}

const handleScroll = () => {
  const scrollPos = window.scrollY
  const progress = getProgress(containerTop, scrollDistance, scrollPos)
  
  slides.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideDistance * progress}px)`
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slide-container{
  height: 400vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-container{
  position:sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slides{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 400vw;
  display:flex;
  border: 5px dashed green;
}

.slide{
  flex: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 400px">Scroll Down</div>

<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="sticky-container">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
      <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!